# How can multiple rows into a single line?

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have a query from one table which returns multiple rows.
I would like is to combine these into one row for each person.

Is there a way to do this?

Example data from query and result I need:

[image: http://upic.me/i/wf/stack.jpg]

Comment: please post your code/queries here.

Answer (score 4):

Use grouping and aggregates:

```
select
  max(Seq) as Seq,
  ID,
  sum(RED1) as RED1,
  sum(RED2) as RED2,
  sum(RED3) as RED3,
  sum(GREEN1) as GREEN1,
  sum(GREEN2) as GREEN2,
  sum(GREEN3) as GREEN3
from
  Table 1
group by
  ID
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad36e/3

Note: You would use different aggregates for the values depending on what result you want if a field has more than one non-null value in a group. Using `sum` gives you the sum of the values in the group, using `max` gives you the highest value in the group.

Comment: why you are doing aggregation operation other than seq?

Comment: @TechnoCrat: To get a reliable result. Some databases allow getting fields that you don't group on (I don't know how Oracle does), but then you have no control over which value you get from the group.

Comment: Yup then you are right otherwise for this given data not required

Comment: @TechnoCrat: It's required. I just tested, and Oracle doesn't allow fetching without aggregates from fields that you are not grouping on.

Comment: Yes you are right and me too checked that for column which not considered for grouping on which aggregation required.

Comment: If some value in REDx & GREENx are string can I use SUM or MAX?

Comment: @skyofwin: You can use `max`, and you can use `sum` if all the strings can be converted to numbers. However `max` on strings will return the string sorted last rather than the highest number, so from the values `'40'`, `'300'` and `'1000'` `max` will return `'40'`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

```
select ID , max(seq) Seq, max(red1) RED1 , max(red2) RED2, max(red3) RED3, 
max(green1) GREEN1, max(green2) GREEN2, max(green3) GREEN3
from Table1
group by ID;
```

Comment: If some value in REDx & GREENx are string can I use SUM or MAX?

Comment: you can use max on strings if you want to show value which is not a null

Comment: @skyofwin, And the column should contain strings only. If a column contains both strings as well as number (of string datatype) then MAX function will return string only.

Comment: @SagarJoon: No, `max` won't return the string with the longest length, it will return the string that is sorted last. From the values `'abc'`, `'abcd'` and `'xyz'` it will return `'xyz'`.